# unexpected std::bad_function_call in recursion

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have written the following code, which plays with functions of type `function<int(int)>`. The functions `compose`, `print`, `inc` and `guarded` are helpers which combine other functions or produce some external effect. Then I use them to build my programs:

```
/* start of the program */
function<int(int)> recursion();

function<int(int)> go =
  compose(guarded(10, recursion()), compose(inc, print("go")));

function<int(int)> recursion() {
  return compose(go, print("recursion"));
}
```

However, when calling `recursion()(0)`, an exception `std::bad_function_call` was thrown when `go` was reached the second time but I don't see why. Is there any dangling reference or empty `std::function`? Moreover, eta-expanding `go` works:

```
function<int(int)> go = [](int n) -> int {
  return compose(guarded(10, recursion()), compose(inc, print("go")))(n);
};
```

What's wrong with the original code? Why does the alternative one work?

Full code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

/* helper functions, some combinators */

//composing two functions, f1 . f2
function<int(int)> compose(const function<int(int)>& f1, const function<int(int)>& f2) {
  return [f1,f2](int n) -> int {
    return f1(f2(n));
  };
}

function<int(int)> print(const string& msg) {
  return [msg](int n) -> int {
    cout << "print: " << msg << endl;
    return n;
  };
}

function<int(int)> inc = [](int n) -> int {
  cout << "in inc lambda: " << n << endl;
  return n+1;
};

//calls the given function `f` only when `n` is less then `m`
function<int(int)> guarded(int m, function<int(int)> f) {
  auto g = [m,f](int n) -> int { return n<m? f(n) : m; };
  return compose(g, print("guarded"));
}

/* start of the program */
function<int(int)> recursion();

function<int(int)> go =
  compose(guarded(10, recursion()), compose(inc, print("go")));

function<int(int)> recursion() {
  return compose(go, print("recursion"));
}

int main() {
  try {
    recursion()(0);
  } catch (bad_function_call e) {
    cout << "bad_function_call: " << e.what() << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your original code, `recursion()` is called during the initialization of `go`. `recursion` itself tries to use the value of `go`, but at that point `go` has not been initialized yet, causing the problem.

In the alternative code, the initialization of `go` only assigns a lambda to `go` without calling `recursion`. When `recursion` is called later, `go` will already have been initialized.

Comment: Oh, right! So calling `go` in the lambda returned by `compose` raises the exception. I forgot to consider the order of evaluation.